# Roles, task, operation

Tags: yii

В Yii новичок!

Для примера. Есть 3 роли - админ (1 чел.), модератор (5 чел.), менеджер (5 чел.).

Есть определенные операции и задачи для них. Как мне для одного конкретного пользователя из группы модератор присвоить еще одну операцию (или задачу), которая доступна только админу? Допустим, createUser.

Использую cdbauthmanager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@zkweb](/users/16475/zkweb)](/users/16475/zkweb), проще всего сделать роль usermanager, присвоить ее конкретному модератору и как дочернюю к админу, и в экшене по созданию юзера проверять ее наличие. Можно еще присвоить конкретному пользователю напрямую таск/операцию, но, как я считаю, юзеры должны наделяться только ролями, а все остальное должен высчитывать граф прав.